# Redirect a specific url before 404 triggers in asp.net web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, web-config, http-error

I have a url, `/example/index.html`, that when hit, I need to redirect to `/`, the root of the page.

The trouble is that this page doesn't actually exists, so I'm just getting a 404 instead.
I want to do it in the web.config file, if possible. This is what I have:

```
<location path="example/index.html">
  <system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

But it seems like the 404 handling is triggering first. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you not using mvc controller?

Comment: @KarthikMR We have controllers, yes, but if they want to change this later, it's easier to have it in the configs.

Comment: Remove location tag and try this - <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="PermRedirect">
         <add wildcard="*.index.html" destination="/" />
      </httpRedirect>
   </system.webServer>

Comment: @KarthikMR Can't get this to work. I actually can't get any redirect to work from the web.config.

Comment: Use this inside <system.webServer> tag. Its working for me:
  <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true">
    <add destination="/" wildcard="*/home/test.html" />
  </httpRedirect>

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside system.webServer tag. Its working for me:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true">
    <add destination="/" wildcard="*/home/test.html" />
</httpRedirect>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Redirection is not available on the default installation of IIS 7 and later. To install it, enable `HTTP Redirection` under `Common HTTP Features`. All the steps for various operating systems are listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/